# How to Control DTMF volume programmatically android

Tags: android, media, dtmf, android-audiomanager

I want to make a Seek Bar that controls DTMF volume(e.g 0 to 100). I have searched a lot but could not find any thing. I am doing this but its not working..

```
int seekbarValue=seekBar.getProgress();
AudioManager audioManager=(AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF, seekbarValue, 0);
```

Please any one tell me a solution to control DTMF volume.

Comment: Hi, do you got any solution to this problem?

Comment: @Dinash No... I searched a lot but could not get right answer :(

Comment: Okay. Thanks for you response. Any work-around you did to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the (`AudioManager.STREAM_*`) volumes go to 100 (int).

A valid stream volume for `setStreamVolume(...)` is between 0 and [`getStreamMaxVolume(int streamType)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamMaxVolume(int)).

Each stream can have a different max volume int, like 8, 10, or 16 from what I remember. Might even be different on different devices.

I hope that is enough to point you and future visitors in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a little more information to the answer of @Anonsage.

As @Anonsage mentioned, each stream has a different max volume. As per Kitkat 4.4.2 implementation, these are the max values.

1. STREAM.DTMF: 15
2. STREAM.MUSIC: 15
3. STREAM.VOICECALL: 5
4. STREAM.RINGTONE: 7

If you actually get into the lower levels and look into the **AudioService.java** of **AOSP** code, there is a rescaling operation that helps to show similar UI and update the actual values of the stream.